# TextInput send text in new td

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a website that the user will put its (Name , LastName , Gender , Age) and it will send the text in the table data .
My first inputs is showing in first table row

I need to put the second inputs in the second table row (can someone help me !) lol

```
                                <h1 align=center>INFORMATION</h1>
            Name:   <input  id="first_name" size="30"  type="text"  action="document.getElementById(f1)">

            LastName: <input  type="text" size="30" id="lastname">

            Age:<input type="text" size="30" id="age">

            Gender: <input type="text" size="30" id="gender">               


             <button class="okok" name="myBtn" type="submit"  value="Submit Data" onClick="ajax_post();">COMPUTE </button>



<table bgcolor ="black"   border="2"    cellspacing=1 align=center  height="100" width="600"> 
<br>

 <tr bgcolor = "black">

 <th width=20 style="color:white;">Name</th>
 <th width=20 style="color:white;">Lastname</th>
 <th width=20 style="color:white;">Age</th>
 <th width=20 style="color:white;">Gender</th>

 </tr>
 <tr>    

 <td style="color:white;" id=f1  >   </td>
 <td style="color:white;" id="no1"> </td>
 <td style="color:white;" id="no2"> </td>
 <td style="color:white;"  id="no3" >  </td>

 </tr>


 <tr>
 <td style="color:white;" id="secondtd1"> </td>
 <td style="color:white;" id="secondtd2"> </td>
 <td style="color:white;" id="secondtd3"> </td>
 <td style="color:white;" id="secondtd4"> </td>

 <td> </td>
 </tr>


 </font>



</table>
```

My script

```
<script>
    function ajax_post(){

      var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
       var table = document.getElementById("f1");
      table.innerText = fn;





       var pre = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
       var table1 = document.getElementById("no1");
       table1.innerText = pre;

       var mid = document.getElementById("age").value;
       var table2 = document.getElementById("no2");
       table2.innerText = mid;

       var fil = document.getElementById("gender").value;
       var table3  = document.getElementById("no3");
       table3.innerText = fil;

}
</script>
```

i have no idea how to do this .. :(

Comment: To start with: enclose the id in quotation marks: id="f1". Also use lowercase letters in onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an example in plain Javascript, here you go. It uses Javascript's [`insertRow`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp) and [`insertCell`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp).

Please keep in mind that this is not an "ajax_post" yet, you will still need to add an actual server request. You might also want to look into Javascript frameworks that handle this, and more, in a cleaner way.

```js
function ajax_post(e) {
  // Prevent the form from actually submitting this.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Save all elements/values we need later in convenient variables.
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var firstname = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;

  // Insert a new row into our table at the position -1 (bottom).
  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  
  // Insert 4 empty cells.
  var cell_firstname = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell_lastname = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell_age = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell_gender = row.insertCell(3);
  
  // Fill the empty cells with the data from the form.
  cell_firstname.innerHTML = firstname;
  cell_lastname.innerHTML = lastname;
  cell_age.innerHTML = age;
  cell_gender.innerHTML = gender;
}
```

```html
<h1>INFORMATION</h1>

<form>
  Name: <input id="first_name" type="text"><br>
  LastName: <input type="text" id="lastname"><br>
  Age: <input type="text" id="age"><br>
  Gender: <input type="text" id="gender"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Compute" onclick="ajax_post(event)">
</form>
<br>

<table bgcolor="black" style="color: white;" border="2" width="100%" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>André</th>
    <td>Eric</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>Male</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible that   i can get the text from my own td without creating new one ?

Comment: Why do you not want to create a new one? Could you explain a little further what you're trying to do?